# window in ovelapping with blank in android

Tags: android, pdf

[below is the layout for your refrence want to display the background layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoW0W.png)Hi in the below code ovelapping layout .It is displaying the layout.But above the layout one more window was displaying with background black.

above that layout having a window that window i can zoom in and zoom out.But this should happens with background layout.

Can any one help me where i did the mistake.

want to display the layout without overlapping

```
private void createPdf(){
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1000, 1000, 2007, 8, -3);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_layout, null);
        // Add layout to window manager
        wm.addView(myView, params);


        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels ;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels ;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

//        Resources mResources = getResources();
       // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext, R.drawable.log);

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

      //  bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
        String targetPdf = "/sdcard/pdffromlayout2.pdf";
        File filePath;
        filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // close the document
        document.close();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PDF is created!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        openGeneratedPDF();

    }

    private void openGeneratedPDF(){
        File file = new File("/sdcard/pdffromlayout2.pdf");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try
            {
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! I would recommend to add a screenshot also to visualize the problem better. I see you have a View in a WindowManager, a PdfDocument and a Canvas. Where exactly do you have the layout issue? Is it in the View, PDF or in the Canvas? These information can help others to give you a better answer.

Comment: @Endanke added the screenshot

Comment: @Endanke did you saw my edit post?

Comment: Yes, thanks for modifying! I'm not sure if I can help you more with this, but someone might know the answer based on the information.

Comment: @Endanke if i commented the canvas